# How to Prevent a request from being cached for LANGUAGE SWITCH routing Laravel Spatie responsecache

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using Laravel Spatie response cache: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-responsecache and Multiple language (language switch..).

How to fix: Preventing a request from being cached for language switcher route in Laravel.

I tried to add: ->middleware('doNotCacheResponse'); in lang.switch route but without success...

```
Route::get('lang/{language}', ['as' => 'lang.switch', 'uses' => 'LanguageController@switchLang'])->middleware('doNotCacheResponse');
```

Expected results to prevent request when switching pages (links) between language to be cached....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly. If the problem is that you get cached results after you select a different language, I think you should clear the entire cache:

```
LanguageController {

    public function switchLang() {
        // Switch language
        ResponseCache::clear();
    }

}
```

Also, seems like spatie/laravel-responsecache allows you to delete specific URIs with `ResponseCache::forget('/some-uri');`

To delete cache after altering your data, do something like this

```
PostController {

    public function index()
    {
        // Display list of posts
    }

    public function edit()
    {
        // Display form to edit post
    }

    public function update()
    {
        // Delete related cache here and update post
        ResponseCache::forget('/posts');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Artjom Heinz,

Where I should add the second code you sent me: ResponseCache::forget('/some-uri');

?!

And please if you can see this problem how to solve it: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-responsecache/issues/156

Comment: Hello,

I am using laravel spatie response cache with my laravel app, when I add some new posts on my website, I dont see the new added post anywhere (on homepage, in posts index page listed).

Why I dont see new added posts?! And how to solve this.

I want to have cached homepage and all index pages but to see new added posts, articles etc?!

What is solution for this ?!

Thanks

Comment: @TarikS. I was just pointing out that it's possible to remove specific URIs **instead of** deleting the entire cache. Whether or not that's something you should do, I don't know. Regarding your second question, I suspect you don't see changes because you're getting the cached response. If so, don't cache dynamic data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658417/handling-caching-dynamic-data

Comment: Helo @Artjom Heinz, 

Yes I am getting cached response I am using spatie for all my routes except update/edit/delete, But when I add new posts/articles for example, I want to view new added articles on my index and show pages but now I dont see them, what should I do here.

You said to not cache, do you mean that than I dont cache index homepage and show pages, but what should than I cache ?!

thanks

Comment: @TarikS.Yes. Simply put, you don't cache somemthing that changes frequently. Typically, you cache things that don't change. The thread I linked to in my last comment explains some caching strategies for dynamic data. If you insist on caching, then you should delete the related cache after changing the data. So maybe if you expect users to add new data very rarely it would make sense to cache but to delete the cache after soemthing has been added.

Comment: yes that is great, for example I have index view page and with $posts , and users adding new data (posts) every 3 - 4 or 5 days, I want to use cache here but to to delete cache for that particular route (view) after new posts are added in database that is it.

I havent seen anything related to this in spatie doc on github can you tell me how can I implement that in my route for example for my homepage for index@BlaBlaControllers.php.... using SPATIE cache....

...Thanks

Comment: @TarikS. I've edited my answer with an example of how this could work.

Comment: I see your updated answer, but it is about update function when I updating some previously added posts for example. But my concern is VIEW AND SHOW blade files.

I explained everything here in this uploaded screenshot below what I need, spatie cache work well, site is fast and good but I have for example on some view blade pages some dynamic data 1 or 2 divs with dynamic data.

Comment: See this:

See this screenshot : https://imgur.com/a/GXPkvQg

 ;;"" I want to cache everything on this page (banners in header, navbar,
 head, footer, everything) except this div (Services) because this is only
DYNAMIC on this page.

That is what I ask you for...""

Comment: Good example.... I want to Cache partials in laravel blade for example just some partials im blade.php where foreach loop is.. that is it...

Comment: @TarikS. The package you are using caches the entire response. You can cache specific data with `Cache::put('key', 'value', $minutes);` as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/cache)